# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument while opening a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am currently working on an application which translates a input file row by row and writes the translated row into a output file but I get the following error when running my script: `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '{parent_id:opynw1, body: my text'`

Full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    column1= GoogleTranslator(source='german', target='english').translate_file(row)
  File "C:\Users\supre\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\deep_translator\google_trans.py", line 136, in translate_file
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\supre\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\deep_translator\google_trans.py", line 132, in translate_file
    with open(path) as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '{parent_id:opynw1, body: my text'
```

Content of my input text file:

```
{parent_id:opynw1, body: my text}
{parent_id:h68dhu3, body: my text}
{parent_id:opynw1, body: my text}
```

My code:

```
from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator

output_file = open('./test.txt', 'w',encoding='utf-8')
reader = open('./data.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
for row in reader:
    column1= GoogleTranslator(source='english', target='german').translate_file(row)
    output_text = str(column1)
    output_file.write(output_text + '\n')
output_file.close()
```

Is there something wrong with my script? If so I would be glad if someone could tell me what I've made wrong and help me to solve this problem:)

Thank's for every help and suggestion in advance:)

Comment: `translate_file()` expects the argument to be a filename. The rows of your input file aren't filenames.

Comment: ooo ok understand:) Thank's for your fast response:)  Do you know how to solve this error?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to translate a large file but the translator only allows 5k characters for each translation. So my plan is it to translate the file row by row to not go over the 5k characters limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `translate()` rather than `translate_file()`, since the line is not a filename.

You also need to use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse it into a dictionary.

```
from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator
import ast

with open('./test.txt', 'w',encoding='utf-8') as output_file, open('./data.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as reader:
    for row in reader:
        d = ast.literal_eval(row)
        column1= GoogleTranslator(source='english', target='german').translate(d['body'])
        output_text = str(column1)
        output_file.write(output_text + '\n')
```

Comment: Thank you very very much Barmar:) This code fixed it for me:)